# Graphs sharing datasets in chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

If I create two separate graphs, each with their own canvas, but the data I initially give them is identical in terms of labels and values, do they then share that object, ie if I add data to it, will that data be seen on both graphs?

Like this twice

```
new Chart(this.ctx, {
  type: `line`,
  data: data,
})
```

when I change the values in that data object, should it affect both graphs?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the charts won't share the same `labels` and `data`, they both keep their own configuration object. This is basically the following part of your code:

```
{
  type: `line`,
  data: data,
}
```

Therefore, you'll have to update `labels` and `data` contained in each chart configuration object and invoke [`chart.update()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) afterwards, same as you do in the code shown in your question: [Chart.js not updating multiple charts independently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70049798/2358409).